# Dynamically loading more data in line chart using MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart library in my app to render a line chart, and am facing an issue while adding more data dynamically to the chart. I tried going through the existing StackOverflow questions and also the GitHub issues for this library, but couldn't find a fix for my issue.

I'm using the LineChart API. In my use case i need to first show 15 data points on the chart, and once the user scrolls to the boundary, I'm fetching 15 more data points from the backend and resetting the data object with the set of 30 data points.

My logic for checking if the user reached the boundary is:

```
@Override
onChartTranslate {
    .
    .
    if (!isLoading) {
        if (lineChart.getHighestVisibleX() == lineChart.getXChartMax()) {
            isLoading = true;
            fetchMoreData();
        }
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Below method fetches data from the backend, and then updates the chart

```
fetchMoreData {
    dataObservable.subscribe(newData -> updateUI(newData))
}
```

the update chart method with additional data

```
updateUI(newData) {
    //from the data received, create new dataset,
    //create a new lineData Object, and add this dataSet
    //set the lineData object on the chart using 
    lineChart.setData(newLineDataSet)

    //view port updates which consist of below
    lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(4);
    lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4);
    lineChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);

    lineChart.moveViewToX(previousBoundary)

    lineChart.highlightValue(previouslyHighlightedValue)

    isLoading = false
}
```

Things work fine for me, when i scroll slowly beyond the boundary, i.e., backend call to fetch additional data is fired and I get the new 15 data points, and I replace the existing lineData object with the new lineData object which has (old + new) data points.

I'm facing an issue if I scroll too quick, that the fetchMoreData is getting called multiple times (2/3 times), and the chart draws more data.

On debugging this I noticed that the lineChart.getHighestVisibleX() method is returning an incorrect value sometimes causing this to happen.

For e.g., the first call is triggered when the highestVisibleX equals the maxX value of 14. This updates the chart with new data points (now 30), and during redrawing of the chart, the onTranslate method gets called and the highestVisibleX somehow returns 29 (same value as maxX for the new data) even though the highest visible x-value is 14.

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not a good one, I did something like below

    if (!isLoading  && (PERMITTED_X_AXIS_RANGE_MINIMUM < visibleXRange && visibleXRange < PERMITTED_X_AXIS_RANGE_MAXIMUM)) {
        if (lineChart.getHighestVisibleX() == lineChart.getXChartMax()) {
            isLoading = true;
            fetchMoreData();
        }
    }

Comment: So, visibleXRange is (highestVisibleX - lowestVisibleX). My chart shows 5 data points at a time, and I'm checking that the range is between 4 (PERMITTED_X_AXIS_RANGE_MINIMUM) and 6(PERMITTED_X_AXIS_RANGE_MAXIMUM). This doesn't work very well, I'm still trying to optimize.